# Error while using interface and Observable with the http parsing

Tags: angular, typescript, http, service, mean-stack

[File Structure in VS with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfH0v.png)

```
app(folder)
  -->employee-list(folder)
       -->employee-list.component.html
       -->employee-list.component.ts
  -->app.component.html
  -->app.component.ts
  -->app.module.ts

  -->employee.json
  -->employee.service.ts
  -->employee.ts
```

Here, all the files are on the same level and I am passing the data from the employee.json to employee component using the HTTP get method. but it is producing the error

> Error
>   **message: "Http failure during parsing for https://htpgeterror.stackblitz.io/employee.json" name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse", error:Object**

**employee.json**

```
[
  {"id":2,"name":"Shiva","age":23},
  {"id":3,"name":"ABC","age":25},
]
```

**employee.ts**

```
export interface Employee {
  id:number,
  name:string,
  age:number,
}
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Employee} from './employee';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
public _url:string="./employee.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getEmp(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

**employee-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EmployeeService} from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
 public employee=[];
 constructor(private _employeeService:EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._employeeService.getEmp()
        .subscribe(data => this.employee = data);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz url https://stackblitz.com/edit/htpgeterror

Comment: `ng serve` (assuming that's what you're using) doesn't serve JSON files at the root. they need to be under assets.

Comment: will you please share the stackblitz so that will fix the error

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/htpgeterror

Comment: I have forked and provided the solution on stackblitz. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to keep you `employee.json` file under the `assets` folder so that angular service can access it properly

**Folder structure**

```
app(folder)
  --> assets (folder)
        --> data (folder)
              --> employee.json // employee data file.
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Employee} from './employee';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
public _url:string="assets/data/employee.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getEmp(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this._url);
  }

}
```

**[Here is forked solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/htpgeterror-7tc5v7?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployee.service.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: Is it always necessary to put the json file in assets /data folder ?

Comment: yes it's the convention, but you can create your own folder and keep this file in that folder. if answer solves your problem please accept so that other will get benefit  out of it

Comment: sorry but now it is giving another error i.e ProgressEvent

Comment: Where you getting error I am not seeing any error on stackblitz

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/htpgeterror-7tc5v7?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployee-list%2Femployee-list.component.html)      with error: **ProgressEvent** and message: **Http failure response for assets/data/employee.json: 0 Unknown Error**  _see in console_

Comment: I have seen your code it's working fine. Please check